# How to localize hibernate (JPA) entities seamlessly on load

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How to localize entities seamlessly ?
I have an object (Entity) with some localized fields and I would like to access those localized fields in this way: entity.getField().

The localization is based on client context.

To achieve this I have used transient fields for localized fields and with help of own Implementation of Hibernate EmptyInterceptor within onLoad method I am setting this fields with localized values. Localised values are kept in separate table.  It is working but I think there should be better solution.

```
@Entity 
public class Card {

    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private String name;



}

@Entity
public class LocalizedCard{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Card card;
    private Language language;
    private String localisedName;

}

and the interceptor

public class MyInterceptor  extends EmptyInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(
            Object entity,
            Serializable id,
            Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames,
            Type[] types) {


        if (entity instanceof Card) {
              Card c = (Card) entity;
c.setName(service.getLocalisedCardName());
return true;
            }



        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "seamless" mean for you? In general I would think this approach is not the best one, localization should be done in the presentation _only_. But when there are good reasons I would put it in the entity with `@PostLoad`.

Comment: seamlees  - I mean that when sombody is working with the entity that he does not to have to bother with the localisations. I know that better is to use localisation only in presentation level. In this case we are using table of (the same) products whith different eans and names for particular country. And those localised fields are used in invoices and etc. (it is eqivalent to pricelist). Also the project uses grids a lot and I was thinking that calling "localisation service" for huge amount of rows and fields would cause performance issues.Anyway, thank you for your  comment.

Comment: I still don't see an immediate need for localizing the entities instead of the presentation and would seriously rethink this. Nevertheless, you can only either cache your service method or do the localization on database level (by joins); probably the latter as that will be what your service method does. But first: Did you measure a performance problem? If yes, it is one that can be resolved cheap by throwing hardware at it?